# Import swf into unity 2d

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, flash

I don't think unity can provide as much animation options as Flash (plz correct me if I am wrong) So I have only two options - Import swf in to Unity OR generate sprite sheet from Flash which is compatible with Unity. I tried many sprite sheet options in Flash but Unity cannot read it well.Unity reads the images from the sprite sheet but misses the transformation coordinates =(. Is there any option to make use of js file generated from flash along sprite sheet image in Unity2d?. Wish some pro is there to help!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool that does that, it's called gaf converter, it's available for Mac and Windows and is free for download http://www.gafmedia.com/

It converts an swf into a generic animation format (.gaf) with atlas that contains sprites and gaf player plug-in for Unity (its link in the Asset Store https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13593 ) allows using this file with Unity.

The good thing is that the tool converts almost anything that can be done in flash without any quality loss.

Comment: There is also a promo link for 500 free conversion with gaf converter http://gafmedia.com/register/promo=unity3d_500 hope it's still valid.

Answer (score -1):

The existing solution provided by Marina Nastenko seems to be valid (following it now), but the link to the Unity addon is dead. Updated link is https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/gaf-free-flash-to-unity-13593.

(I'd have posted this as a comment, but I don't currently have the reputation to do so.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33425283)